# Install OS X Cheetah on my Macbook Air with OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, virtualbox

How can I install Cheetah (OSX 10.0) on my 2014 Macbook? Can I use virtual box? Where can I find iso files to install? BTW my macbook is running Yosemite

Comment: Virtualizing Mac OS X Cheetah is not allowed by its SLA.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to virtualize the hardware. [PearPC](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/) claims to successfully run Mac OS X 10.3, so my best assumption is that it would also run 10.0.

The matter of obtaining and running the OS on your computer is of dubious legal nature, depending on where you live and what licenses you accepted when you purchased and ran the OS.

Answer (score -1):

Any ISO file is likely pirated. Best to buy a CD on the used market or find a local computer group that has a library. If you wanted to be totally legal, buy a used Mac that came with that OS.  Replacement media is often available from Apple even long after they stop selling a certain OS.

I can't speak to virtual box other than it's taking more fiddling then I cared to spend. I go with VMWare or Parallels for my virtualization.

Comment: Does any popular virtualization suite (VMWare, VirtualBox, Parallels) actually emulate PowerPC? Cheetah is not an x86 OS. [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_10.0).

Comment: Yes @ChrisHarrington - you are correct that one VM tech won't be enough to run PPC code directly on intel hardware. Adding PPC emulation will be a second level of indirection. See SheepShaver and various mods if you are adventurous. I didn't answer with these since I doubt they are stable enough for general use with the hardware specified.